# Putting Stack in descending order using push and pop in python

Tags: python, sorting, stack, push

- accepts strings from user and generates stack till it gets the input "End"
- Next, it should sort the given stack in a decent order
- Finally, print the sorted stack

I cannot seem to get the logic right using only push and pop methods whereby push is a function putting elements to the top of the stack and pop is a function removing the top element of the stack and storing it. I am only allowed to use push and pop, the sorting algorithm is the only one I cant do.

```
from Stack import Stack

def display_(S_):
    node = S_.list.head

    while node != None:
        print(node.data)
        node = node.next
        

def Sorting_Stack(stack,k):
    v = 0
    ar = 0
    temp = Stack()
    for i in range(k):
        v = stack.pop()
        temp.push(v)
        node = stack.list.head
        tnode = temp.list.head
        if tnode.data > node.data:
            ar = temp.pop()
            stack.push(ar)
            
    display_(stack)
        
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    stack = Stack()
    string = ""
    k = 0
    while string!='End':
        string = input()
        if string == 'End':
            break
        else:
            stack.push(string)
        k += 1
    
    Sorting_Stack(stack, k)
```

#this is Stack.py--------

```
from Node import Node
from LinkedList import LinkedList

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = LinkedList()
        
    def push(self, new_item):
        # Create a new node to hold the item
        new_node = Node(new_item)
        
        # Insert the node as the list head (top of stack)
        self.list.prepend(new_node)
    
    def pop(self):
        # Copy data from list's head node (stack's top node)
        popped_item = self.list.head.data
        
        # Remove list head
        self.list.remove_after(None)
        
        # Return the popped item
        return popped_item
```

Comment: Are you using a LinkedList as a Stack ?

Comment: this is what the drill by the instructors used. The only bits I was to edit is the __main__ and the sorting function

Answer (score 0):

#Stack Class

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self):
    self.stack = []

def push(self,item):
    if item == 'End':
        self.sort()
    else:
        self.stack.append(item)

def pop(self):
    if len(self.stack) == 0:
        print("Stack Is Empty")
    else:
        self.stack.pop()

def sort(self):
    self.stack.sort()
    print(self.stack)
```

**logic For giving Inputs**

```
s = Stack()
item = None
while item !='End':
    print("Type 'End' For Ending the Stack Push Operation")
    item = input("Enter Item: ")
    s.push(item)
s.push(item)
```

**Program will take inputs till we give input as 'End'.
After given 'End' as Input it will sort the stack and print it.**